# count how many tensor in each tensor between 2 tensors are exactly equal

Tags: python, pytorch

Since I have learned metric 0/1 loss for multi-label classification, and I need to create that metric

so I would like to `def check` that could count and return how many inside tensor between two tensors are actually matched

For Example

```
# Only second inside tensor are exactly equal

a = torch.tensor([[1,0,1,1], [1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1]])
b = torch.tensor([[0,0,1,1], [1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0]])
check(a,b) -> 1
```

AND

```
# Only second and third are exactly equal
c = torch.tensor([[1,0,1,1], [1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1]])
d = torch.tensor([[0,0,1,1], [1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1]])

check(c,d) -> 2
```

My question is that how could we define function check to retrieve 2 tensors and return the following expected output, Thank you in advanced

Comment: There are many ways you can do this, subtracting one tensor from the other  then summing values and finding the non zero tensors, to simply using python's built in `==` function. What have you tried?

Comment: Oh You are right! Let me try

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my question, Thanks to the combination of @Zwang
and @LudvigH advice,

> There are many ways you can do this, subtracting one tensor from the
> other then summing values and finding the non zero tensors, to simply
> using python's built in == function. What have you tried? - Zwang

I tried one of his methods, and that's answering my question :D, and fixed bug by @Ludvigs

```
def check(a,b):

    assert a.size() == b.size()      
    diff_tensor =  a - b                  # [1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]
    diff_tensor = torch.abs(diff_tensor)  # In case summation of them are neglect to zero, Credit goes to @LudvigH
    diff_scalar = torch.sum(diff_tensor, dim= 1) # [1 , 0 , 0]
      
    return torch.numel(diff_scalar[diff_scalar==0])
```

Comment: There is a bug here. You can fix it by e.g. take the absolute value of the diff_tensor. Consider the case `a=torch.tensor([[1,0]])` and `b=torch.tensor([[0,1]])`.

Comment: .. or use `diff_tensor = a == b`. That is also fine.

Comment: Thank you, that was an unexpected bug, I have edited my question to solve from your advice.. Thanks